# I want a way to rewrite this with less repetition

Tags: javascript, angular

So I have two conditions here with some changes in the UI. Is there a way to rewrite it in a better way?

```
<i *ngIf="measures.length > 0">
  <ul *ngFor="let m of measures">
    <io-data-selection-row
      [text]="m.getDisplayName()"
      [id]="m.getId()"
      (deleteIconClicked)="removeSelected($event)"
    ></io-data-selection-row>
  </ul>
</i>
<ul *ngIf="measures.length <= 0">
  <io-data-selection-row
    [strikeThrough]="'strikethrough'"
    [text]="selected"
    [id]="selected"
    (deleteIconClicked)="removeSelected($event)"
  ></io-data-selection-row>
</ul>
```

Comment: If you're looking for advice on how to improve working code, [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) may be a more appropriate forum.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `*ngIf="measures.length"` for !== 0 and `*ngIf="!measures.length"` for === 0

Comment: nice thanks! , but do you think there is any better way to rewrite this to avoid repetition ?

Comment: This is as short as it gets. You can still shift the logic into the component and just call a method within the template. But this will just make it a bit more readable at best.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngIf-else, but I don't think there's a much shorter way:

```
<i *ngIf="measures.length; else nolength">
    <ul *ngFor="let m of measures">
        <io-data-selection-row [text]="m.getDisplayName()" [id]="m.getId()"
            (deleteIconClicked)="removeSelected($event)"></io-data-selection-row>
    </ul>
</i>

<ng-template #nolength>
    <ul>
        <io-data-selection-row [strikeThrough]="'strikethrough'" [text]="selected" [id]="selected"
            (deleteIconClicked)="removeSelected($event)"></io-data-selection-row>
    </ul>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have few ways to achieve this.

1. Use ngStyle or ngClass for dynamically change the style properties
2. If you want modifications in the existing code then go for the
   below.

.

```
<div *ngIf="measures.length > 0; then thenBlock; else elseBlock"></div>
 <div> 
  <ng-template #thenBlock>
   <ul *ngFor="let m of measures">
    <io-data-selection-row
     [text]="m.getDisplayName()"
     [id]="m.getId()"
      (deleteIconClicked)="removeSelected($event)">
    </io-data-selection-row>
   </ul>
  </ng-template>
 <ng-template #elseBlock>
  <io-data-selection-row
   [strikeThrough]="'strikethrough'"
   [text]="selected"
   [id]="selected"
   (deleteIconClicked)="removeSelected($event)">
  </io-data-selection-row>
 </ng-template>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another aproach is, when you get the measures, make a map (I supose you're getting from a service), or use an if, e.g. some like

```
this.serviceData.getMeasures.pipe(
    map((res:any[])=>{
       if (!res || res.length<=0)
          return [{text:'selected'}] //<--change to fit in your requeriments
       return res;
    }).subscribe(res=>{
           this.measures=res;
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add like this and check if it works?

```
<i>
  <ul *ngFor="let m of measures">
    <io-data-selection-row
      [strikeThrough]="!m && 'strikethrough'"
      [text]="m ? m.getDisplayName() : selected"
      [id]="m ? m.getId() : selected"
      (deleteIconClicked)="removeSelected($event)"
    ></io-data-selection-row>
  </ul>
</i>
```